# How would the identity of a company be discovered through banner ads?

Tags: user-tracking, geolocation, user-enumeration

Our company has started researching using a new tech. We started seeing banner ads for a consulting company "with expertise in" this new tech.

The recently we had a call from someone representing this consulting company.

We have not publicly discussed what we are doing with this project, and we have not been advertising for developers with skills in this tech.

I understand that searching on google refines your search profile to deliver better search results and better targeted ads.

I am guessing the consulting company is using target ads to show up based on what our team is searching.

**How did this company discover who we are just based on displaying us some banner ads?**

Is this a threat we need to worry about?

How would we defend against it?

Comment: This is essentially the same question [you've asked already yesterday](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/178971/how-would-the-identity-of-a-company-be-discovered-through-banner-ads) from the perspective of somebody trying to advertise - and which got closed as off-topic and then deleted by you. It looks like you are now trying to play the same game again but claim that you are the one which got the targeted ads instead of  the one who placed the ads - but you probably still want to find out how such ads can be placed.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich It seemed easer to start fresh (clean slate so to speak, to gather my thoughts and ask a good question). I had a look though the help center, as far as I can tell this question is on topic. If you think it is not, How should this question be altered to be on topic for this site?

Comment: Your previous (deleted) question and your comments in it focused on how you could place such ads yourself to find companies which use the technology you are interested in. Therefore  I'm in doubt if this questions presents a case which happened in reality or if you just made up such a case in order to find out which technologies you might use to achieve your goal. Apart from that, please have a closer look what the tags you use actually mean. At least `user-enumeration` has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I was wondering if the banner ads would be trying to access resource on linkedin (or some where), seeing if they got a 401 or a 403 response depending on if the user was logged in or not. Then enumerating through all the users they know are located in their target market. If it is not the right use case for that tag then I can remove it.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich And although my (deleted) question came across the wrong way (I was trying to make it sound more interesting to get a better response, I do do may best work after midnight I will have to say), this is a real scenario. Day 2 of a new job for a government department, working on a new project, I started receiving  spam emails on this new project area. I had not even sent an email outside of the department and I have a pretty uncommon name. I do not know how else they would have know to send email on that topic to darcy.thomas@departmentIWorkAt.gov.country.

Comment: In this case I recommend to describe the actual case in more detail in your question instead of abstracting or simplifying it too much and this way omitting information which might be helpful in explaining what you see. For example: in the last comment you say that you've got a mail on your fresh work address while in your question you talk instead about a call received.